# Why does the keyboard change and editText box lose focus in android studio project?

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard

Ok, first time poster. I teach in High School, first year on job no mentor to help, so if my code is garbage, be gentle.

Problem: : This program is to keep inventory for poptarts being sold. In the XML I have a linear layout, listview, and finally a linear layout. The listview goes through, uses a custom adapter to show the current pop-tarts  and has an edit text to update the count. The last linear layout has edit texts to add a new poptart to the arraylist. After I added this code, whenever I select the edit text in the listview (which I forced to be an input_type:"number") the number pad pops up and then disappears to be replaced by the normal qwerty keyboard and the edit text box loses focus. If I jab the edit text box 3-4 times quickly it will keep the number keypad up and maintain focus. I just can't figure out why the focus and keyboard are being changed.

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
<TextView
   ...
<TextView
    ...
<TextView
   ...
<TextView
   ...
<TextView
    ...
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/flavor"

    android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#000"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newFlavor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Flavor"
        android:textSize="10pt"
         />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/isSeasonal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:checked="false"
         />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newCurrent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Current"
        android:textSize="10pt"
         />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newMax"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:hint="Max"
        android:textSize="10pt"
         />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewFlavor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside of list_view_inventory.xml:

```
...
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
 ...
```

Finally I'll post MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PopTart> {
ArrayList<PopTart> popTartList = new ArrayList<>();
Button buttonOne;
CheckBox seasonal;
public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<PopTart> tarts){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, tarts);
    popTartList = tarts;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_inventory, null);

    TextView nameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    final TextView countView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count);
    final EditText countUpdate = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    CheckBox seasonal = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.seasonal);

    //Tried to force the input type again here programmatically
    countUpdate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    nameView.setText(popTartList.get(position).getName());
    countView.setText(String.valueOf(popTartList.get(position).getCount()));
    seasonal.setChecked(popTartList.get(position).getmSeasonal());
    seasonal.setEnabled(false);

    buttonOne = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.increment);
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (countUpdate.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
             {
            //Making sure the EditText isn't empty
            }
            else {

            String temp2 = countUpdate.getText().toString();
            PopTart temp = popTartList.get(position);
            temp.setCount(Integer.valueOf(temp2));
            popTartList.set(position, temp);
            countView.setText(String.valueOf(popTartList.get(position).getCount()));
            countUpdate.setText(""); }


        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

Thanks for all you do, Stack Overflow Community! You have taught me so much already!

Comment: why to Force input type, you can write it in xml, android:inputType="number"

Answer (score 3):

In Android 7, I did not see this problem but I also having this problem recently at older version of Android. 
I solved this problem by adding the following three.

1: Set **android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"** on the listView.

> FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS 
>   added in API level 1
>   int FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS
>   This view will get focus only if none of its descendants want it.

2: Add the following to your EditText 
**android:focusable="true"

android:focusableInTouchMode="true"**

3: Add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** to activity of your manifest file. So your list can be scrollable even when keyboard is appeared.

PS: If someone facing the same problem, I hope this can help to them.

Comment: oh jeez. #1 did remove my issue. I had this problem in android 6.0.1. Still have a problem with my first textview of the first row being focused on after change.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `list_view_inventory.xml` should look like as follows, just added `android:inputType="number"` in your `EditText`

```
...
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
 ...
```

Or request focus programmatically.

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

you can even remove code which sets input-type to EditText in `getView()` method of your adapter.

Quoting Android docs

> whenever the ListView needs to display a particular row of data, it requests the associated adapter to provide the view corresponding to that the data at that position through getView() method. This may occur whenever the view needs to be updated on screen (eg. during creation/scroll etc.).

so `inputType= "number"` is specified whenever `getView()` is called, and then it falls back to default inputtype and popsup qwerty keyboard.

I think it will solve your problem.

### **EDIT**

So you can use following

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

To get desired result, remove previous `<requestFocus/>`

Comment: So I tried this solution first, and then tried to force it in the adapter. I went back and took out all the input requirements in the XML. The issue I have now is that when I select the EditText in the listview, it loses focus again until selected a second time, then it will hold focus. So I think it is less of an input issue and more of a focus issue.

Comment: Updated answer, try implementing that.

Comment: This works, kinda. I don't want the edit text to have focus unless touched, and the <requestFocus /> causes the edit text to be automatically selected on creation, which is not desired. also the wrong keyboard still comes up, even with inputType="number". The number keyboard pops up and then disappears immediately.